# Creating new columns in CSV based on recursive search

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-4.0

I'm trying to process a 15MB CSV file that has only three columns. For example:

```
StaffNumber,EmailAddress,Manager
123,ArthurDent@beeblebrox.com,456.
```

I need to search each line of the CSV file, display the staff number, email address, then take the Manager's ID number and search for that, displaying their staff number and e-mail, then take *their* manager's ID and repeat the same. In the end, I need to have each row of the CSV file have the user's ID and e-mail, and **up to three managers ID's and e-mails**.

I'm trying to end up with this:

```
123,ArthurDent@beeblebrox.com,456,Marvin@beeblebrox.com,789,Zaphod@Beeblebrox.com,098,zaphod@beeblebrox.com
```

Some rows don't contain an e-mail address or manager's ID number, so that throws another wrench into the works. I was planning on adding simply "Blank" or "X" to those fields.

So far, I've hammered out this simple script to search one at a time. It works, but it's atrociously slow. Since this morning, it's taken 6 hours to get 0.31% through that file. Ugh!

I've read until I thoroughly confused myself about how best to handle 15MB worth of CSV data, different PowerShell versions, what's best this week, etc, and PowerShell is far from my usual language (take pity on my lack of PS skills. I was just trying to flesh out a basic test script to get an idea).

I'm currently running PowerShell v4, and I know there are compatibility issues with earlier versions. I'd like to try to stay as compatible with future versions as reasonable.

What would be the fastest way to process this file?
 At only 15MB for 300,000 lines, I'm not concerned about RAM. I just have no idea how to more efficiently run this search.

```
$FilePath = "C:\Temp\DA-UserList.csv"
$DAUserlist = Import-CSV $FilePath

$inputNumber = Read-Host -Prompt "Employee ID Number"

$DAUser1 = $DAUserlist | Where{$inputNumber -match $_.StaffNumber}| Select -First 1
ForEach ($item in $DAUser1){
    $StaffNumber1 = $($item.StaffNumber)
    $EmailAddress1 = $($item.EmailAddress)
    $Manager1 = $($item.Manager)
    printf $item.StaffNumber
    printf ","
    printf $EmailAddress1
    $DAUser2 = $DAUserlist | Where{$Manager1 -match $_.StaffNumber}| Select -First 1
    ForEach ($item in $DAUser2){
        $StaffNumber2 = $($item.StaffNumber)
        $EmailAddress2 = $($item.EmailAddress)
        $Manager2 = $($item.Manager)
        printf ","
        printf $StaffNumber2
        printf ","
        printf $EmailAddress2
        $DAUser3 = $DAUserlist | Where{$Manager2 -match $_.StaffNumber}| Select -First 1
        ForEach ($item in $DAUser3){
            $StaffNumber3 = $($item.StaffNumber)
            $EmailAddress3 = $($item.EmailAddress)
            $Manager3 = $($item.Manager)
            printf ","
            printf $StaffNumber3
            printf ","
            printf $EmailAddress3
            $DAUser4 = $DAUserlist | Where{$Manager3 -match $_.StaffNumber}| Select -First 1
            ForEach ($item in $DAUser4){
                $StaffNumber4 = $($item.StaffNumber)
                $EmailAddress4 = $($item.EmailAddress)
                $Manager4 = $($item.Manager)
                printf ","
                printf $StaffNumber4
                printf ","
                printf $EmailAddress4
                printf \n
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think for 15MB file, you don't need any hardcore optimizations (at least I think so). So what you are looking to use is a recursive function, as you are doing the same thing over and over again.

```
$data = Import-Csv "C:\Temp\DA-UserList.csv"
$i = 0

function Get-CsvUser {
    param(
        [string]$id
    )

    $data.Where({$_.StaffNumber -eq $id}, 'First', 1)
}

function Get-CsvNested {
    param(
        [string]$id
    )

    $user = Get-CsvUser $id
    Get-CsvUser -id $user.Manager | % { 
        while ($global:i -lt 3) { # using global here to avoid circular execution
            $global:i++

            Write-Output "User: $($user.EmailAddress)"
            Write-Output "His Manager: $($_.EmailAddress)"

            "" # to output an empty string
            Get-CsvNested -id $_.StaffNumber
        }
    }
}
```

that would at least look better and be easier to understand, as for the performance, try using the `.where()` [method](http://ss64.com/ps/where-method.html). It is faster.
Also, you could split the CSV into chunks and create a separate process to parse out chunks (think Start-Job or better [Start-RSJob](https://github.com/proxb/PoshRSJob))

the code above is for a single user (and his managers) look up, and I'm not sure what your end goal is, since you worded it quite poorly (well, I didn't understand it).

If you need further help ping me here (or somewhere, check my profile), we can work something out.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you execute something like `$DAUserlist | Where { # ... } | Select -First 1` you are doing a linear search through, as you say, 300,000 records.  You can speed this up by using the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/3.0/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) like so...

```
$DAUserlist = Import-CSV $FilePath
$DAUsersByStaffNumber = $DAUserlist | Group-Object -Property 'StaffNumber' -AsHashTable
```

`$DAUsersByStaffNumber` contains a [`HashTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.collections.hashtable.aspx) instance mapping each staff number to a user record.  Your code to lookup a given user and their three managers could then be replaced with the following...

```
$DAUser1 = $DAUsersByStaffNumber[$inputNumber]
# ...
$DAUser2 = $DAUsersByStaffNumber[$Manager1]
# ...
$DAUser3 = $DAUsersByStaffNumber[$Manager2]
# ...
$DAUser4 = $DAUsersByStaffNumber[$Manager3]
```

That simplifies the code a little bit and makes your lookups a lot more efficient.

Also, something else to be aware of is that when you are filtering your user list by staff number you are using the `-match` operator, which supports regular expressions, whereas the `-eq` operator would look for an exact string match (case-insensitive).  One reason this could be an issue is that using `-match` when you don't intend to do complex string matching supported by regular expressions could result in reduced performance compared to `-eq`, though perhaps imperceptibly so.  More importantly, since you have 300,000+ users then some of your `StaffNumber` values must be at least six digits long, and depending on how your CSV is formatted (is `StaffNumber` zero-padded to the maximum number of digits?) and sorted it's possible you could match the wrong user.  For example, if `$inputNumber` is `12345` then it would match user `12345` but also users `112345` and `123450` among others.  If it is your intention to only allow searching by exact staff number then switching to `-eq` or the `HashTable` solution above will accomplish that.